# VueJs as separate Installation or use VueJs within Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

We are going to start a project using Laravel and VueJs. What we need is Whether we keep VueJs as separate Installation or Use Within Laravel Installation. Which will be better. And one more thing, we are planning is, for all small pages we use laravel-> blade and for big pages which takes time to load we think we use VueJs and Laravel Api. Is that fine. Can any give some Suggestion regarding above 2 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you completely separate Vue.js Front-end to Laravel Back-end, then I believe there are some benefits and losses
Benefits

1. You can easily scale the app as it is decoupled.
2. Additional backend services can be added via other backends(like in my case I made a some Deep learning code in Python).
3. use of third party front end app integration becomes easier.

Cons

1. Routing and Permissions need to be done separately, so It is double effort in intial stages, Also Laravel is reduced to just creating APIs only.
2. JWT Authentication also requires more effort.
3. Might have to run a nodejs process for your Vue.

I don't find any problem using blade with either completely separate frontend and backend or backend with laravel.

Comment: I need some resources about roles and permissions when laravel and vuejs are separate applications. Would you please share some resources about it!

Comment: @RashedHasan read about vuex or pinia and watch laracasts videos about using authorization for inertia you can get some idea

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, you should install Vue.js and Laravel different place, because if I don't remember wrong, `babel` of Vue.js and `laravel-mix` of Laravel will be conflicted if you use both in the future. So I prefer not to install Vue.js and Laravel at the same place.

And about your second question, I recommend you should not mix 2 type of page rendering for both back-end and front-end like that, only use one, for code's consistency.
**For Example**: You can consider one of these following way:

- Use Laravel for back-end only rendering admin page and building API, and Vue.js get data from Back-end API and render it on frond-end (client-side).
- Use Laravel totally for back-end API and Vue.js for rendering layout
  for both side (admin and client).

I think with that, it would be easier for another developer to follow up your code flow.

Hope it would help you. Please correct me if I were wrong

Comment: we are going to create Admin Section only and this admin section is used by many clients. And client request this admin to load all pages quickly. So what will be your opinion using Laravel and Vue

Comment: In my opinion, as I told you, it's depend on what you want to build, if application contains both admin-side and client-side, as you can see, those 2 ways above I mentioned are all use Vue.js for rendering client page (the reason why is it would look more professional to Client if it's SPA - fast and no reload page). So if admin section is used by many clients, as you said, client-side I think the best way is create a SPA, so that it will effect to User Experience (UX) a lots.